# Why ZIP is so efficient on System.Random generated sequences - where is Kolmogorov complexity?

Tags: random, zip, compression, complexity-theory

I'm generating sequences of random numbers. Sequences include only 0's and 1's. I put every sequence in a separate text file and then I try to archive the file (to .zip format). I'm using System.Random to generate the elements of each sequence. At a first look, the sequences seem to be indeed random.

The weird thing is that no matter what is the size of the generated .txt file, the size of the compressed .zip file is always equal to the same ratio ~17% of the size of the .txt file.

But in theory, for a really random sequence the compressed .zip file should be almost equal in size to the .txt file - i.e., there should be almost no compression. Otherwise the sequence is at least partially predictable (which is impossible in this "flip coin"-like experiment).

So it means that my "archiver" knows how to recognize that the sequence is generated by a particular pseudo-random generator realized in System.Random.

Here I have 2 questions:

1. how to generate a pseudo-random sequence that wouldn't be compressable by the archiver? Maybe there are some known tricks?
2. why the ratio 17% is so stable and doesn't depend on the length of the sequence (i.e., on the size of the .txt file).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you saving the numbers in text, i.e. as ASCII characters? If so, you are not actually storing random sequences.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler Yes, I simply store characters. But I'd like to try another way of storage. Will try with binary arrays.

Comment: A code example of how you store your numbers would be helpful. There are many ways to store 1's and 0's :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You state that you're only saving 0s and 1s in your text file. Thus, at binary level, your file consists entirely of occurrences of the bit sequences `00110000` and `00110001` (which correspond to the ASCII values for the characters `'0'` and `'1'`). This is hugely wasteful, and a good compression algorithm would realize that it can represent each of these 8-bit patterns with a smaller number of bits: optimally 1, but probably a combination of 1 and 2 bits to get the ~18% compression ratio that you quote.

If you want to create a sequence that cannot be compressed, you need to generate random unbounded values, and write these as binary to the file. For example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];   // for a 1 MB file
(new Random()).NextBytes(buffer);        // each byte gets a random value from 0 to 255
File.WriteAllBytes(target, buffer);
```

Comment: Note that technically, this sequence is highly compressible.  E.g., a SFX archive could encode it as a seed, a length, the PRNG algorithm (and boilerplate).  Even cryptographic PRNGs are compressible, if you know the seed.